# Mysql query help required using GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have a table with 2 columns, following is my table structure

**referral_id | status**

```
531 | 0
531 | 0
531 | 3
530 | 3
529 | 3
528 | 3
527 | 3
527 | 0
527 | 0
523 | 2
523 | 0
523 | 3
522 | 3
522 | 3
522 | 3
522 | 3
511 | 3
```

My expected output is

**referral_id | status**

```
530 | 3
529 | 3
528 | 3
522 | 3
511 | 3
```

The 1st column referral_id can have multiple tuples with same id (see referral_id's 531 and 527). I need to make sure that tuples with same referral_id get eliminated if all of their corresponding "status" are NOT 3. If all of the corresponding "status" are 3 then I need to apply GROUP BY to get that referral_id(s) in result. "status" column can have values from 1 to 4, but I just need to look for 3. So how can I achieve this result ?

Comment: Wait, are you sure you mean `remove if ALL are not 3`? Because since 527 has a 3, that would mean 527 would be in the results. Or do you mean `remove if not all are 3`?

Comment: @Konerak what I understood is that we need to show all referral_id's when all of the status for that referral_id are equal to 3.

Comment: *mutters something about epsilon-delta formulations*

Comment: @Konerak yes, i need all referral_ids which dont have status 3

Comment: @BugFinder I tried this SELECT a.referral_id
FROM referral_practitioners a
JOIN referral_practitioners b
ON a.referral_id = b.referral_id
AND b.status <> 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about ...

```
select referral_id, max(status)
from tablename
group by referral_id
having max(status) = 3 and max(status) = min(status)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `group by`, just do it like this:

```
select distinct t.referral_id
from tablename t
where t.referral_id not in (
                            select referral_id
                            from tablename
                            where status <> 3
                           )
order by t.referral_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `NOT EXISTS`

```
Select referral_id,  status
FROM yourtable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  select 1 
  from yourtable b 
  where b.referral_id = a.referral_id 
  and b.status != 3)
```

Comment: your second query is wrong. I think it'll ll select all data.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this

```
select referral_id from table
group by referral_id 
having (min(status)=3 and max(status)=3 and count(status)=3) or (count(status)<3)
```

Comment: why the `count`'s? He doesn't need to be exactly 3 rows for each group.